# Groovy and grails jdk issue

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, groovy

I wish I could give you guys more information on what's going on, but I really have no idea.  I am trying to install groovy and grails tools suite from springsource and I am having trouble configuring it to work properly.   I have the most up to date JDK, and the preferences show it, but I still get warnings and it does not build.  I have posted some pictures below to show what is going on.

[image]

[image: Shows JDK found and installed]

[image: java home]
[image]

Comment: Don't know if this will help anyone or not, but i'm able to run grails from command line

Comment: Try to install http://www.springsource.org/sts and install plugins for Groovy and Grails support. It should work without any other adjustments.

Comment: @OndrejKvasnovsky still have the same problem

Comment: Does your `c:/dev/JDK 1.7.13/` contains `tools.jar`?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov no it did not. I just added the jdk from my laptop and it worked

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. on your GGTS go to window
2. select java
3. select installed JREs
4. add-> Standard VM
5. jRE home select directory up to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18
6. select jdk1.6.0_18 from installed JREs

Comment: If you're using Eclipse you have to go this way:
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue (I am sure it is the exact issue) - Here are the steps to ensure it works correctly, I struggled with initially but this got it going.

1. Install JDK from http://www.java.com ,in a directory where there are **NO SPACES** in the path
2. Set **JAVA_HOME** to your JDK installation
3. Ensure  **%JAVA_HOME%\bin;** is in your **PATH** variable.
4. On the command prompt run ***java -version***, it should give you the path where JDK is installed
5. Install STS Springsource Tool suite.
6. Run your STS and create a new grails project and run it.

Let me know if that does not work.

Comment: Still did not work after that, just coppied the jdk from my laptop

Comment: You need to install JDK in a directory where there are no spaces. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you are launching Eclipse with a JRE even though you have a JDK installed as one of the compilers in your workspace.  To find out if you are launching with a JRE or JDK, go to Help -> About GGTS -> Installation details -> Configuration

Look for the `-vm` option and make sure it is a JDK not a JRE.