# Grails - can't find JDK

Tags: java, grails

Recently in Grails I had to re-download fresh copies of a project - and I have the new JRE and JDK installed.   But now is Grails is nagging me and saying my project is only using a JRE - how can I double-check this?

Answer (score 1):

Check your JAVA_HOME system environment variable is pointing to the JDK, not to the JRE.

Comment: yep my JAVA_HOME is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25

Comment: When you change the JAVA_HOME environment variable all cmd windows and IDE software has to be restarted because they use the old settings. You should try this. I have no other idea.

Comment: sorry meant to clarify - my JAVA_HOME was set that way all along.  I haven't changed.  And grails still nags me with that warning.

Comment: It's odd that I am getting this error - because I am able to do grails run-app with no problem, and my project works fine in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Which IDE are you using, if any? It could be some config issue within your IDE. Try compiling/running a grails application from the command line and see if that works. (If it's GGTS, you should have a look here for some ideas: [Groovy and grails jdk issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663528/groovy-and-grails-jdk-issue))

Otherwise, have you added JAVA_HOME\bin to your PATH environment variable?

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Comment: Yep, working in GGTS.   grails run-app works fine from cmd prompt.   and JAVA_HOME\bin is already in the PATH variable

Comment: Ok, have you checked that GGTS is pointing to the correct JDK?

In GGTS, select the Window menu->Preferences.  Then select Java->Installed JRE’s.  Then click Add… select Standard VM then click Next.  In the JRE home, navigate to the folder you’ve installed the JDK to.
Now click Finish. 
This will bring you back to the installed JRE’s window, unclick the JRE and click your newly added JDK.

Comment: I did all that just like you said and unclicked the JRE, and it still gives me that error.

Answer (score 0):

First let understand how `JAVA_HOME` works for grails.
Grails expectation is clear about it, Its expect `JAVA_HOME` should point to java installed main directory not bin directory.

```
D:/Program File/java/java_1.8/
```

[image]

[image]

Above path is for java main Directory. So for the grails `JAVA_HOME` must be point to JAVA main dir.

But one problem is there if we set `JAVA_HOME` to main java dir. Our `javac` and `java -version` will stop working.

And solution for above problem is very simple. Need to add `\bin` after `%JAVA_HOME%` path variable.

```
Path Variable :: %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

[image]

Now restart the CMD terminal and check `grails` and `java` versions.

```
grails -version
java -version
```

Now it should work!.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with Grails 3.1.4. I set the JAVA_HOME variable to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73
```

instead of

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin
```

And then it was found.